# Getting error when adding custom domain to Azure staging web app blade

Tags: azure, dns

We are wanting to create a subdomain, `staging.example.com`, to point to a staging blade in Azure. We are following this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

When we get to step 5, ("Click Save to save the domain name configuration"), we get this error:

> Failed to update SSL settings for prayrchainangular(staging): There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.

We've set up an A record and two CNAME records as follows:

A record:

- `staging` -> `[IP address]`

CNAME

- `awverify.staging` -> `awverify.example-staging.azurewebsites.net`
- `staging` -> `example-staging.azurewebsites.net`

Any ideas why we are getting this Azure error and cannot save our domain name to the staging blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the old portal:

Select your website from the list >> Dashboard >> Custom Domain (bottom bar)

or Sign out / Sign In again.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially here's what happened. We were trying to use the new beta Azure at https://portal.azure.com instead of the old portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com. This article below steered us in the right direction:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance

That first CNAME above (`awverify.staging`) was completely unnecessary. All we needed was the second one.

What's confusing is that the staging blade is a child of the main web app, and you cannot get to this staging blade on the **All Items** tab in the old portal. You have to go to **Web Apps**, and then you see an arrow to the left of each web app that toggles its hidden children. We pretty much spent an hour+ figuring that out.